# Draw a semicircle that has a segment as its diameter

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

I'm trying to draw a simple schematic of an ATM machine and I can not represent the counter. The schema of a counter is a semicircle with a segment. Their position is on the right extreme and on the bottom (I managed to draw only the segments).

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amsthm, amsmath, braket}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes,calc,patterns}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (1.5, 0.5);

        %== CUBO
        \draw[thick] (1.5, 0.25) -- (3,0.25);
        \draw[thick] (3,0.25) -- (3, -0.25) -- (4, -0.25) -- (4, 0.75) -- (3, 0.75) -- (3, 0.25);
        \draw[thick] (3, 0.75) -- (3.3, 0.95);
        \draw[thick] (4, 0.75) -- (4.3, 0.95);
        \draw[thick] (3.3, 0.95) -- (4.3, 0.95);
        \draw[thick] (4, -0.25) -- (4.3, -0.05);
        \draw[thick] (4.3, 0.95) -- (4.3, -0.05);

        \draw[dashed] (5.5,0.21) -- (4, 0.21); 
        \draw[dashed] (5.5,0.29) -- (4, 0.29); 
        \draw[thick] (4.3, 0.21) -- (5.5,0.21);
        \draw[thick] (4.3, 0.29) -- (5.5,0.29);

        \draw[thick] (5.5,0.29) -- (5.5, -0.25) -- (5.8, -0.05) -- (5.8, 0.95);
        \draw[thick] (5.5,0.29) -- (5.5, 0.75) -- (5.8, 0.95);

        \draw[dashed] (5.5, 0.21) -- (5.8, 0.21);       
        \draw[dashed] (5.5, 0.29) -- (5.8, 0.29);

        \draw[thick] (6.5, 0.29) -- (6.5, -0.25);
        \draw[thick, ->] (6.5, 0.29) -- (6.5, 0.95);

        \draw[thick] (5.8, 0.21) -- (7.5, 0.21);
        \draw[thick] (5.8, 0.29) -- (7.5, 0.29);

        \draw[thick] (7.5, 0.25) -- (7.5, -0.25) -- (8.5,-0.25) -- (8.5, 0.75) -- (7.5, 0.75) -- (7.5, 0.25);
        \draw[thick] (7.5, 0.75) -- (8.5,-0.25);

        \draw[dashed] (7.5, 0.21) -- (8, 0.21) -- (8, -0.22);
        %P_\theta
        \draw[thick] (8, -0.22) -- (8, -1.5);
        \draw[thick] (8, -1.5) -- (7.5, -1.5) -- (7.5, -2.5) -- (8.5, -2.5) -- (8.5, -1.5) -- (7.5, -1.5);

        \draw[thick] (8, -2.5) -- (8, -3.5);
        \draw[thick] (8, -3.5) -- (7.5, -3.5);
        \draw[thick] (8, -3.5) -- (8.5, -3.5);

        %P_\varphi
        \draw[thick] (7.5, 0.29) -- (10, 0.29);
        \draw[thick] (10, 0.29) -- (10, -0.25) -- (11, -0.25) -- (11, 0.75) -- (10, 0.75) -- (10, 0.29);

        \draw[thick] (11, 0.29) -- (12.5, 0.29);
        \draw[thick] (12.5, 0.29) -- (12.5, -0.3);
        \draw[thick] (12.5, 0.29) -- (12.5, 0.8);
        %\draw (12.5, 0.8) arc (-90:180:1);


    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how you want it, but here is a suggestion:

(The code can be simplified, but that's not really necessary, since that is just a quick answer.)

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amsthm, amsmath, braket}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, quotes,calc,patterns}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (1.5, 0.5);

        %== CUBO
        \draw[thick] (1.5, 0.25) -- (3,0.25);
        \draw[thick] (3,0.25) -- (3, -0.25) -- (4, -0.25) -- (4, 0.75) -- (3, 0.75) -- (3, 0.25);
        \draw[thick] (3, 0.75) -- (3.3, 0.95);
        \draw[thick] (4, 0.75) -- (4.3, 0.95);
        \draw[thick] (3.3, 0.95) -- (4.3, 0.95);
        \draw[thick] (4, -0.25) -- (4.3, -0.05);
        \draw[thick] (4.3, 0.95) -- (4.3, -0.05);

        \draw[dashed] (5.5,0.21) -- (4, 0.21); 
        \draw[dashed] (5.5,0.29) -- (4, 0.29); 
        \draw[thick] (4.3, 0.21) -- (5.5,0.21);
        \draw[thick] (4.3, 0.29) -- (5.5,0.29);

        \draw[thick] (5.5,0.29) -- (5.5, -0.25) -- (5.8, -0.05) -- (5.8, 0.95);
        \draw[thick] (5.5,0.29) -- (5.5, 0.75) -- (5.8, 0.95);

        \draw[dashed] (5.5, 0.21) -- (5.8, 0.21);       
        \draw[dashed] (5.5, 0.29) -- (5.8, 0.29);

        \draw[thick] (6.5, 0.29) -- (6.5, -0.25);
        \draw[thick, ->] (6.5, 0.29) -- (6.5, 0.95);

        \draw[thick] (5.8, 0.21) -- (7.5, 0.21);
        \draw[thick] (5.8, 0.29) -- (7.5, 0.29);

        \draw[thick] (7.5, 0.25) -- (7.5, -0.25) -- (8.5,-0.25) -- (8.5, 0.75) -- (7.5, 0.75) -- (7.5, 0.25);
        \draw[thick] (7.5, 0.75) -- (8.5,-0.25);

        \draw[dashed] (7.5, 0.21) -- (8, 0.21) -- (8, -0.22);
        %P_\theta
        \draw[thick] (8, -0.22) -- (8, -1.5);
        \draw[thick] (8, -1.5) -- (7.5, -1.5) -- (7.5, -2.5) -- (8.5, -2.5) -- (8.5, -1.5) -- (7.5, -1.5);

        \draw[thick] (8, -2.5) -- (8, -3.5);
        \draw[thick] (8, -3.5) -- (7.5, -3.5);
        \draw[thick] (8, -3.5) -- (8.5, -3.5);

        %P_\varphi
        \draw[thick] (7.5, 0.29) -- (10, 0.29);
        \draw[thick] (10, 0.29) -- (10, -0.25) -- (11, -0.25) -- (11, 0.75) -- (10, 0.75) -- (10, 0.29);

        \draw[thick] (11, 0.29) -- (12.5, 0.29);
        \draw[thick] (12.5, 0.29) -- (12.5, -0.3);
        \draw[thick] (12.5, 0.29) -- (12.5, 0.8);
        \draw (12.5, -.3) arc (-90:90:.55);


    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the solution !! You talk about simplifications, can you give me some suggestions for improve my knowledge about tikz?

Comment: @IImionome456: Actually yes – there are just (at least for me) two big tips: (1) pracitce a lot – this means that you try to do almost everything in Ti*k*Z (street signs, things that you see in everyday life) and (2) when you start to code you have always to ask you: What exactly do I want to draw/do; What is the rough idea to achieve this; After the idea is completed than you have to see some things that can be simplified – through expirience or questions.